# I can't run any project using libraries?

Tags: python, terminal, pip, ide, importerror

I have every library installed using pip;
when I write the code, IDE doesn't show any errors; but when I want to run the code, IDE has ImportError for every function;
I think The Problem is sth about my terminal, but I'm not Really Sure.

Comment: Please show the code

Comment: Edit your post to include the full error message you get. Also do you have 2 versions of Python installed? It might be that pip is, for example, installing things in Python2 but then you are trying to run the code in Python3 which causes the error

Comment: ImportError: No module named wordcloud_fa @CoderCharmander

Comment: I'm using pip3 and python3 to download and install each library; I have both python versions but I don't use python2. @KJTHoward

Comment: did you check what version of Python IDE is using?

Comment: yes; Visual Studio is using python 3.8.0 and also pip3 version is updated !@Sankar

Answer (score 0):

Go to the "terminal"(for PyCharm)/"console"(for Spyder) of the IDE you are using, and install the packages using pip in that terminal, it should work!

Problem is the packages you have installed using pip is not being mapped to the IDE

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Code and I did what you said in VSCode; but the problem still exists!

Comment: I have never used Visual Studio Code, but I have faced the same issue with PyCharm IDE, and when I installed the packages in the console comes with the IDE, my code ran!